# ReactPlayer won't show some videos from vimeo

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vimeo, react-player

I have a React App that uses ReactPlayer to reproduce videos, which are from Vimeo or YouTube. My problem is that, for some reason, some videos from Vimeo are not shown.

The way I'm implementing ReactPlayer is:

```
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'

...

<ReactPlayer
    url={url}
    controls={true}
    width={'100%'}
/>
```

where url is the URL of the video.

If the URL comes from YouTube, there's no problem, but if the video comes from Vimeo, some of them are not shown - just totally blank.

Some YouTube videos are not available, in those cases, ReactPlayer shows a message saying "Video unavailable", wouldn't it be happening with Vimeo, but ReactPlayer is not displaying anything in those cases - any ideas why? If this happens, what could I do to warn the user?